# How to make function return string in c++

Tags: c++, string, function, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert this code to use string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792736/how-to-convert-this-code-to-use-string)

I have a function like this:

```
char *foo()
{

}
```

How can I make it return a string instead? I tried

```
string foo()
{

}
```

but the compiler complains.

Comment: what's the complaint?

Comment: Well, it might issue a warning about no return value :vP .

Comment: My advice is to start with Hello World. Clearly you know how to program, but just need to get the compiler working.

Comment: @sbi, a complaint is a tool for converting code to executable programs? (SCNR either :) )

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you do this:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

And additionnally, do you use `gcc` or `g++`? Even if `gcc` now can compile C++ code, it is advised to use g++.

Comment: I forgot the using std::string. That was the problem.

Comment: [`-1` for suggesting a using declaration.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136)

Comment: this is not like suggesting a using namespace, heh.

Comment: The only thing you did forget is to type "std::" in front of standard library classes/functions. Don't take the habit of "using std::string;" or "using namespace" everywhere. ( especially inside .h header files )

Answer (score 7):

Try std::string. Standard features are in the std:: namespace.

```
std::string foo() 
{ 

}
```

Be careful with "using" directives, especially in header files. Better take the habit to use std::